# There is an error appears when I visit the back-end

Tags: magento2, error, backend

Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

When I access the back-end, sometimes there is an error as following.

Does someone has the same issue and were able to fix it?

Any ideas how to fix it?

I am happy for any ideas!

Thanks for helping.

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: efdd144c177f76a85eb59cb370ff0e99ff425aa122932e0604b8023729cae91a

And the file "efdd144c177f76a85eb59cb370ff0e99ff425aa122932e0604b8023729cae91a" I have this


{"0":"Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(\/var\/lib\/session\/sess_s28439ejde6euu7bchsnh1lrv6, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler\/Native.php on line 22","1":"#1 SessionHandler->read() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler\/Native.php:22]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SaveHandler\\Native->read() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler.php:138]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SaveHandler->callSafely() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SaveHandler.php:83]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SaveHandler->read()\n#5 session_start() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SessionManager.php:204]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SessionManager->start() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/Auth\/Session\/Interceptor.php:37]\n#7 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session\\Interceptor->start() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Session\/SessionManager.php:141]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SessionManager->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/Model\/Auth\/Session.php:101]\n#9 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session->__construct() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/Auth\/Session\/Interceptor.php:14]\n#10 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session\\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:66]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:167]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:273]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:236]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:167]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:273]\n#21 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:236]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#25 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:203]\n#26 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->parseArray() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:179]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:273]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:236]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:34]\n#30 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->_resolveArguments() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:59]\n#31 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#32 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:71]\n#33 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->__construct() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:14]\n#34 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->__construct() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/AbstractFactory.php:121]\n#35 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/Factory\/Dynamic\/Developer.php:66]\n#36 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Dynamic\\Developer->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/ObjectManager\/ObjectManager.php:70]\n#37 Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:115]\n#38 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#39 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:40]\n","url":"\/admin_mqimtc\/","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"efdd144c177f76a85eb59cb370ff0e99ff425aa122932e0604b8023729cae91a"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are receiving indicates that there is no space left on the device where Magento is installed. Specifically, it appears that the error is related to a failure to open a session file.

To resolve this issue, you will need to free up some space on the device. This can involve deleting old files or transferring them to another device or cloud storage. You should also consider optimizing your database and removing any unnecessary backups or logs.

Once you have freed up space, clear the session files and cache by following these steps:

1. Navigate to the root directory of your Magento installation.
2. Delete all files in the var/cache/ directory.
3. Delete all files in the var/session/ directory.
4. Restart your web server.